# Copy current text and change it

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have lots of URLs in an spreadsheet, I need upload it in the following format:

It is currently like this:

```
http://url.com/this_is_an_example
http://url.com/another_example
```

I need it like this:

```
http://url.com/this_is_an_example, http://url.com/this-is-an-example
http://url.com/another_example, , http://url.com/another-example
```

I know i can just use find & replace to replace _ with - but how can i copy the same url next to the exisiting one?

I'm using Openoffice Calc

Thanks

Comment: Why the Excel tag? Either you need a solution for OOCalc or Excel. The two are not always mutually compatible. Don't throw mud at a wall to see what sticks.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky How can i copy 20,000 URLs and paste them next to the current one with a comma separating them?

Comment: @Jeeped Because if it's only possible in Excel and not OpenOffice, i will buy Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the two solutions is the delimiter used for the concatenate and substitute statements i.e. ";" vs ",".

**Openoffice Solution:**

```
=CONCATENATE(A1;", ";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"_";"-"))
```

Result

[image]

**Excel Solution:**

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,", ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","-"))
```

Result
[image]

> I know i can just use find & replace to replace _ with - but how can i
>   copy the same url next to the exisiting one?

In the end, you could hide the original column and leave the custom column.